# Log4net custom adapter for asynchronous functionality

Tags: asynchronous, log4net

Following is what I need to achieve through Log4net. 
My application has a 3rd party dll, which relays logs to Splunk synchronously RelayLogsToSplunk(Dictionary ). The API takes a dictionary of strings and send them synchronously to splunk. The synchronous function is significantly slowing down my application.
I need to extend Log4net capability (appenderskeleton class maybe), which can adapt to this third party API and make the logging to splunk asynchronous. In other words, a layer between logger and the API, which would make the operation asynchronous. Can anyone please help me with the design?
Thanks
Sudarshan

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of log4net, then the [Log4Net.Async](https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async) library will be the best place to look - previous versions included an `AsyncAppender` in the source samples.

For best performance, you also want to buffer log events, so the [`AsyncForwardingAppender`](https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async/blob/master/src/Log4Net.Async/AsyncForwardingAppender.cs) will probably be all you need, wrapped around your `Splunk` appender, and you can use the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Log4Net.Async/) to install it. Alternatively, if you think you need something more customised, get the source and there are lots of examples of how to do async logging.

One thing to note [from the documentation](https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async):

> If the Log4Net.Async library is only referenced in non-code (eg. a
>   log4net log.config file), then the VS build process will not
>   automatically copy the Log4Net.Async dll to the build folder for
>   projects that reference other projects using Log4Net.Async. This
>   occurs even if Copy Local is set to "True".
>
> To get around this some of our users have created a dummy class whose
>   sole purpose is to extend the RingBuffer class, without actually doing
>   anything or being used anywhere at all.